# Need advice to make php server side Datatables work properly

Tags: php

There's something weird going on with server-side Datatables from this: https://github.com/n1crack/Datatables.

Don't understand what's going on, i do exactly the same thing as the examples but it simply doesn't work. According to the "where" example https://github.com/n1crack/Datatables/blob/master/public/examples/where/ajax.php, look how simple it should be:

```
$dt = new Datatables(new MySQL($config));
$dt->query("Select film_id as fid, title, description from film where film_id > 47 and film_id < 83");
echo $dt->generate();
```

My code:

```
$config = [ 'host'     => 'localhost',
        'port'     => '3306',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'sys_db_gincana' ];

        $dt = new Datatables( new MySQL($config) );
        $dt->query("
        SELECT seen, id, name, cep, date_format(created,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') as created
        FROM user
        ");

        echo $dt->generate();
```

Now look at what my js console prints from my ajax:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message:  Argument 1 passed to
>   PHPSQLParser\builders\WhereBuilder::build() must be of the type array,
>   boolean given, called in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\gincana\vendor\greenlion\php-sql-parser\src\PHPSQLParser\builders\SelectStatementBuilder.php
>   on line 74 and defined
>
> Filename: builders/WhereBuilder.php
>
> Line Number: 112
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()
>
> Filename: builders/WhereBuilder.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 114
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message:  Argument 1 passed to
>   PHPSQLParser\builders\WhereBuilder::build() must be of the type array,
>   boolean given, called in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\gincana\vendor\greenlion\php-sql-parser\src\PHPSQLParser\builders\SelectStatementBuilder.php
>   on line 74 and defined
>
> Filename: builders/WhereBuilder.php
>
> Line Number: 112
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()
>
> Filename: builders/WhereBuilder.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 114
>
> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function
>   fetch_assoc() on a non-object in **C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\gincana\vendor\ozdemir\datatables\src\DB\MySQL.php**
>   on line **40**

And if if i change the query to:

```
        $dt = new Datatables( new MySQL($config) );
        $dt->query("
        SELECT seen, id, name, cep, date_format(created,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') as created
        FROM user
        WHERE approved = 0 and canceled = 0
        ");
        echo $dt->generate();
```

the error changes:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is
>   not an array
>
> Filename: src/Datatables.php
>
> Line Number:
>   47
>
> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function
>   fetch_assoc() on a non-object in **C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\gincana\vendor\ozdemir\datatables\src\DB\MySQL.php**
>   on line **40**

Well, the library is a bit new (january 2015), i wonder if someone that had success using it could help me.
Regards

Comment: added readability for the error code

Comment: The query builder is failing to compile the query appropriately, or has changed what it returns. Did you try a basic query without the use of functions (like `DATE_FORMAT`) and aliases?

Comment: yes sir, indeed i tried already without the aliases, the formats and the where, but no result so far

Comment: maybe i should post here the methods that build the query? it's a third party library called php sql parser that the n1crack's lib uses

Comment: Yeah, i looked at it already. I would say that if you cannot get even a basic query to run, then i would open a ticket on Datatables or PHPSQLParser... seems somehting is definitely a miss. You can reference this question as well. I suspect the dependency isnt pegged to major version and is using dev-master or version range where something with the API or internals of the parser have changed.

Comment: hum, yeah you're right, i kinda totally agree with you. Help me figure out something plz, it doesn't have anything to do with Datatables itself has it? i should open a ticket for the PHPSQLParser right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the WhereBuilder comes from the PHPSQLParser, can you test the latest version from https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser? It seems to be a simple SQL statement, so actually it should work. I have moved your issue to [GitHub](https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser/issues/185), please follow the changes there.